# How to embed one layout inside another in my case?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

If I have a layout called ***bottom.xml***,

***bottom.xml:***(simply contain a textview and edit text view)

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
     >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:text="@string/username"

        />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/name"

            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"     
        />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way to **embed** the above ***bottom.xml*** layout inside other layouts instead of repeatly writing the same code in several layout files (when other layouts have a part which contains the same layout as bottom.xml)?

For example, if my ***admin.xml*** layout also contain part of the layout which looks exactly the same as ***bottom.xml***, how to just embed the ***bottom.xml*** inside ***admin.xml*** instead of writing the same code again?

***admin.xml:***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
     ...
     ...
        <!--How to embed bottom.xml here-->
     ...
 </LinearLayout>
```

If there is no way to do it in Android, what could be the workaround??

**----------Update-----------**

Like @xevincent suggested, I can reuse the ***bottom.xml*** by use `<include>` tag,

But How to change the id of the elements inside the resued layout?

For example, insdie ***bottom.xml***, I would like to change the id of `<editText android:id="@+id/name">` to  `<editText android:id="@+id/other_name">` when I reuse the ***bottom.xml*** layout in other layout, how to change the id ?

Comment: Possible solution to your "update": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421864/how-do-i-access-the-views-inside-the-layout-when-i-reuse-it-multiple-times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this doc [reusing layouts](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html).

Comment: @ xevincent , How to change the id of the elements inside the resued layout e.g. bottom.xml, I would like to change the id of editText when I reuse the bottom.xml layout in other layout, how to change the id ?

Comment: You can't change the id of the elements inside bottom.xml in the xml way but you can do it in Java (See View.setId(int)).

Answer (score 2):

Just upvote xevincent's anwser. I added this answer because SO recommends to "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

So, basically, [his link](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) explains that you should use `<include />`.

```
<com.android.launcher.Workspace
    android:id="@+id/workspace"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    launcher:defaultScreen="1">

    <include android:id="@+id/cell1" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />
    <include android:id="@+id/cell2" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />
    <include android:id="@+id/cell3" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />

</com.android.launcher.Workspace>
```

And know that you can override the layout parameters:

```
<include android:layout_width="fill_parent" layout="@layout/image_holder" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this doc, Link updated

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html