# Include same layout multiple times

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a common layout (common.xml) which I want to include many times in another layout (layout_a.xml). But it only shows me just one time. Why?

**common.xml**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame">

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"

            android:src="@drawable/test"

            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:text="test"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

**layout_a.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/common" />

    <include layout="@layout/common" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 13):

The ids when defined in XML must be unique. You are including two layouts that have views that contain the same id.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421864/how-do-i-access-the-views-inside-the-layout-when-i-reuse-it-multiple-times) is how you would go about fixing it.

p.s. Unless there is more code that you are not including in your first layout file, that merge tag is useless.

Answer (score 10):

As [btse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931938/btse) said, the ids in the XML must be unique.
It can be achieved in this way:

```
<include android:id="@+id/common1"
    layout="@layout/common" />

<include android:id="@+id/common2"
    layout="@layout/common" />
```

For information about how to access the elements inside those two included views, you can check out [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170429094622/http://www.coboltforge.com/2012/05/tech-stuff-layout/) blog post.

Comment: Please fix link

Comment: Updated the link to the wayback machine version of the article.

Answer (score 2):

That's what I had done in my Project with `Inflater`.
`test1`is just a Layout made with a `LinearLayout(Vertical)` with text and a button and `mainofferslayout` in that case, the main layout with an image.

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers_display, container, false);

    View inflatedLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, (ViewGroup) view, false);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainofferslayout);

    ll.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, (ViewGroup) view, false));
    ll.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, (ViewGroup) view, false));
    ll.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, (ViewGroup) view, false));
```

Answer (score -3):

I fixed by setting the layout_height of the RelativeLayout to 250dp since they are overlapped.