# Set text of Android RemoteViews inside layout when include it multiple times

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-remoteview

I refer to this question:
[How do I access the views inside the layout when I reuse it multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421864/how-do-i-access-the-views-inside-the-layout-when-i-reuse-it-multiple-times)

I have the following two layouts:

```
<!-- layout_to_include.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<!-- widget.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/included_layout_1"
        layout="@layout/layout_to_include"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/included_layout_2"
        layout="@layout/layout_to_include"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Normally, you can access the TextViews programmatically inside the included layout like this:

```
LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.included_layout_1);
((TextView) l1.findViewById(R.id.text_view)).setText("test1");

LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.included_layout_2);
((TextView) l2.findViewById(R.id.text_view)).setText("test2");
```

But in my case, I have an Android AppWidget which can only accessed via RemoteViews:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, "test1");
```

This will only change the text of the first TextView.

I have not find any solution, so my question is whether is it possible to set the text of the TextView within multiple included layouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can be done.

Remove your `include`s; you need to add **programmatically** (no other way AFAIK), so add id (e.g. `LinearLayout`) to your widget's linearlayout, and:

```
RemoteViews one = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_to_include);
one.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, "tv-ONE"); // <---
remoteViews.addView(R.id.LinearLayout, one);

RemoteViews two = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_to_include);
two.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, "tv-TWO"); // <---
remoteViews.addView(R.id.LinearLayout, two);
```